Is H. H. Hoppe considered a good philosopher?
What is the general consensus (in philosophy circles) about the work of Hans Hermann Hoppe? In particular I'm interested in his proof that a priori knowledge exists (in his book A Theory of Socialism and Capitalism).
I haven't gone back to read more in detail but the proof seemed good and, at the same time, the type of delicate proof that crumbles if one comma is out of place.
I think I was shocked that he first proves that knowledge of language is a priori. This conclusion in particular is a bit difficult for me to accept. Is it commonplace in philosophy?
My last question is on where people think Hoppe's arguments fail. As I see it, if he is correct then we all should be turned into voluntarists / anarcho-capitalists. Given that only a few people are, where in his arguments does he fail according to everyone else?
Thanks in advance

From skimming "A Theory of Socialism and Capitalism," he's wrong about lots of stuff. He claims, for example (beginning on page 134), that we know a priori that it is impossible for our actions to be caused by time-invariant laws of physics. This is because, he says, to predict what we'd do based on new knowledge would require us to already have that new knowledge, which would be a contradiction. This is a conflation of what we can practically predict with what is theoretically determined. We cannot practically predict our future actions, but nonetheless we can theoretically understand how they are caused, and how they are caused is independent of whether we theoretically understand how they are caused.
The basic problem here is that he's not understanding the mind as a machine, which it is. Let's apply his same argument against our actions being caused, to the actions of a computer. A computer can't predict what it would do if it downloaded a program it doesn't have yet - because to  predict what it would do it would need to first have the program. This is exactly analogous to Hoppe's argument about humans trying to predict how they would act if they had new knowledge. But it is obvious that a computer's actions are almost entirely deterministic, with predictable physical causes that do not change over time. So Hoppe's argument is reduced to absurdity.
